# In PyParsing, how to setParseAction on a delimitedList to convert it to a Python list

Tags: python, pyparsing

I'm trying to extract a `delimitedString` as a list using PyParsing as follows:

```
from pyparsing import *

string = "arm + mips + x86"
pattern = delimitedList(Word(printables), delim="+")("architectures")
result = pattern.parseString(string)
print(dict(result))
```

The problem is that this prints

```
{'architectures': (['arm', 'mips', 'x86'], {})}
```

which is the string representation of a `ParseResult`. However, I would like the result to be a Python list:

```
{'architectures': ['arm', 'mips', 'x86']}
```

I've looked into doing this with `setParseAction`, but I wasn't able to figure out how to achieve this using the API of that method. I would actually like to apply `list()` to the entire `ParseResult`, but the `setParseAction` functions have to have the original string, locations, and tokens as input (cf. http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/HowToUsePyparsing).

How can I post-process the result to make it a list?

Comment: Instead of `dict(result)`, does `result.asDict()` give you what you want? You may need to elaborate on just what the problem is with having a ParseResults instead of a list. Is it the ugly output? A marshalling issue? Converting to json?

Comment: [Edit] your Question and show `print(type (result))`.

Comment: Pyparsing is no longer hosted on wikispaces.com. Go to https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting to an answer [PaulMcG](https://stackoverflow.com/users/165216/paulmcg)'s comment, `result.asDict()` yields the desired result.